# pandas merge two dataframes by one offset

Tags: python, pandas

I have two dataframes. The dataframe A is like below

```
         date          quantity   
0  2008-08-08          1000  
1  2008-08-11          2000  
2  2008-08-12          3000
.....
```

The dataframe B is

```
         date          address   
0  2008-08-08          xyz  
1  2008-08-11          abc  
2  2008-08-12          def
.....
```

Our goal is to merge `B[index]` with `A[index - 1]`. Note that the date is not continuous, thus we cannot simply increase the date by one day and merge on date.

Our expected dataframe is

```
         date          address    quantity 
1  2008-08-11          abc        1000
2  2008-08-12          def        2000
.....
```

Note, the index 0 with date `2008-08-08` is discarded as there is no row `A[-1]`.

Comment: Could you reset B's index to start at 1 (using `range`) and then merge on index?

Comment: Are you actually merging on the date?

Comment: "abc" and "2000" already occur on the same date/index. Is your expected dataframe correct?

Comment: @CameronRiddell You are right, sorry for that. I've corrected it. Thanks.

Comment: @rhug123@Paul H  Please refer to the updated dataframe. I've tried `join` on `index`, but it does not produce expected results.

Answer (score 0):

Shift the index of one and then merge.

```
'''
import pandas as pd
df_res = pd.merge(df_A.shift(1),df_B, how='inner')
'''
```

Shift df_A by one & merge on the index.

Comment: This works `result = pd.merge(A.shift(1), B, how='inner', left_index=True, right_index=True)`

Comment: `result.drop('date_x', 1).dropna()`